# How to get AJAX results first and only then run next function

Tags: javascript, ajax, stapes.js

Ok, Here is the situation, I am validating a `form`. This form has 4 input boxes. 2 validations are done on this form.One validation checks if 3 boxes have some values(doing this with `parsely`). One box has some code and I have to send this code to server to run a check if the code is valid. Here is How I am doing this:

(pseudo code)

```
onFormSubmit(){
    var isValid,

    //This is a callback and to get the result of ajax. Ajax function is in different file
    validateCode = function(response){
         isValid = response; // true or false
    };

   isValid = $('#form').parsley('validate');

    //Calling that other file function for ajax result, arguments are passed as object validateCode is function name.
   this.emit('validateCode', {value:promoCodeValue, validate:validateCode});


   // Here in this function, the value of isValid is not updating properly. It is taking the value given by parsley validation.
   doOtherStuff(isValid)

}
```

So my question is, is there any way with the help of which I could wait for the ajax to complete and then run `doOtherStuff` function.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to rearrange your code a bit.

```
onFormSubmit(){
    var isValid;
     //This is a callback and to get the result of ajax. Ajax function is in different file
     validateCode = function(response){
         isValid = response && $('#form').parsley('validate'); // true or false
         //Calling that other file function for ajax result, arguments are passed as object validateCode is function name.
         this.emit('validateCode', {value:promoCodeValue, validate:validateCode});
         // Here in this function, the value of isValid is not updating properly. It is taking the value given by parsley validation.
         if(isValid){
              doOtherStuff(isValid);
         }
     };
}
```

Comment: there is a condition on `doOtherStuff` it is like this : 
`if(isValid){doOtherStuff();}`  so problem is it is not waiting for validate code to execute.. it simply goes to else condition

Comment: do you face the problem with the above code as well? I edited it slightly. IN this scenario it will wait for the ajax response and then call doOtherStuff() after validating the response and the javascript validation.